# How can I isolate a string between two characters (RegEx)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `before = '<ii_226@tet.jpg>'` and want to isolate everything between the < >.

The result should be `after = 'ii_226@tet.jpg'`

I tried:

`after = before.match(/(<(.*?)>)/);`

but I will get an array as a result:

`[ '<ii_226@tet.jpg>', '<ii_226@tet.jpg>', 'ii_226@tet.jpg', index: 0, input: '<ii_226@tet.jpg>, groups: undefined ]`

Basically, I only need the third entry of the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just get the third entry out of the array. What you're seeing is the normal way that the `.match()` method works.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will it always be the third entry?

Comment: The first entry (index 0) is the complete text of what was matched overall. After that, there's an entry for each `( ... )` capturing group. With your regex, there are two capturing groups, one inside the other, so there'll always be something in entry 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across an easier way to do it:

Since ES2018 you can use Lookaheads and Lookbehinds:

`after = before.match(/(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)/g);`

Together with the /g option, this will create an array with only one entry:
`['ii_226@tet.jpg']`